# What's the best mock framework for Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

What's the best framework for creating mock objects in Java? Why? What are the pros and cons of each framework?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

I've had good success using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito).

When I tried learning about JMock and EasyMock, I found the learning curve to be a bit steep (though maybe that's just me).

I like Mockito because of its simple and clean syntax that I was able to grasp pretty quickly. The minimal syntax is designed to support the common cases very well, although the few times I needed to do something more complicated I found what I wanted was supported and easy to grasp.

Here's an (abridged) example from the Mockito homepage:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

List mockedList = mock(List.class);
mockedList.clear();
verify(mockedList).clear();
```

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

The only major downside I can think of is that it won't mock static methods.

Comment: Beautiful. For static methods, simply combine Mockito with JMockit and there is practically no class too "legacy" for you to be able to test.

Comment: I love how when you try to do something you shouldn't (e.g. create mocks inline), you get a very clear explanation of what you did wrong in the exception message.

Comment: +1 for Mockito. Even though nowhere mentioned, it seems heavily inspired by Ruby's Mocha framework (which is great).

Comment: The only think I don't like about mockito is that you cannot use it for android, other than that is a great framework

Comment: For me, absolutely. I would still recommend it unconditionally. Of course, if you find another framework that better meets your needs, mention it in another answer and see what votes it gets and what kinds of comments it receives.

Comment: @MexicanHacker why couldn't you use it for Android? I'm using it right now, with Robolectric.

Comment: @Ilkka It's hard to remember now, the problem was in March 2010, at that moment mockito was not able to mock finals, which is something you'll find a lot in Dalvik, here is more info: https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/

Comment: I´ve experienced with EasyMock and I find it quite easy to use... so if mockito is easier I guess it is REALLY easy and it deserves a try.

Comment: @MexicanHacker, PowerMock extends Mockito so you can run Android tests natively on the host PC.

Comment: I'm using Mockito and loving it!! Great documentation too (so rare to find documentation of this quality, good job from the  authors), which is so important for us to use stuff without having to dig into the framework's code!!!

Comment: As Jan Kronquist says in his answer, you can use PowerMock to extend Mockito if you need to mock static methods.

Comment: @MexicanHacker looks like there's been some work in Mockito recently to support Android. I don't know anything about it, but it's mentioned here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#28

Answer (score 84):

I am the creator of PowerMock so obviously I must recommend that! :-)

[PowerMock](http://powermock.org) extends both EasyMock and Mockito with the ability to [mock static methods](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic), final and even private methods. The EasyMock support is complete, but the Mockito plugin needs some more work. We are planning to add JMock support as well.

PowerMock is not intended to replace other frameworks, rather it can be used in the tricky situations when other frameworks does't allow mocking. PowerMock also contains other useful features such as [suppressing static initializers](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) and constructors.

Comment: Powermock is essential for unit testing Android applications using native Java on the host PC (avoiding using the slow emulator)

Comment: @Jan only issue is PowerMock is incompatible when using Robolectric though :-( I want to do @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) AND @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

Comment: After using PowerMock for the past few months I heartily recommend it!

Comment: PowerMock really is awesome. I really love static singletons to access everything, and this makes that possible to test.

Comment: Caveat: some things like mocking final methods are only possible in Powermock for EasyMock and not for Mockito. It's a bit of a gotcha when you don't use it that frequently. I was wondering why something wasn't working then I realised it's only listed under the Easymock section of the doco.

Answer (score 46):

The [JMockit project site](http://jmockit.org) contains plenty of comparative information for current mocking toolkits.

In particular, check out the **[feature comparison matrix](http://jmockit.org/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix.html)**, which covers EasyMock, jMock, Mockito, Unitils Mock, PowerMock, and of course JMockit. I try to keep it accurate and up-to-date, as much as possible.

Comment: I am impressed by JMockit, it has a steeper learning curve, but it has very good documentation for years, and it can mock anything. I started with Mockito, which was easy to learn, but I regularly met problems which I could not solve with it. On the other hand I cannot even imagine what is impossible with JMockit.

Answer (score 21):

I've been having success with [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/index.html).

It's pretty new, and so it's a bit raw and under-documented.  It uses [ASM](http://asm.objectweb.org/index.html) to dynamically redefine the class bytecode, so it can mock out all methods including static, private, constructors, and static initializers.  For example:

```
import mockit.Mockit;

...
Mockit.redefineMethods(MyClassWithStaticInit.class,
                       MyReplacementClass.class);
...
class MyReplacementClass {
  public void $init() {...} // replace default constructor
  public static void $clinit{...} // replace static initializer
  public static void myStatic{...} // replace static method
  // etc...
}
```

It has an Expectations interface allowing record/playback scenarios as well:

```
import mockit.Expectations;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExpecationsTest {
  private MyClass obj;

  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    new Expectations(true) {
      MyClass c;
      {
        obj = c;
        invokeReturning(c.getFoo("foo", false), "bas");
      }
    };

    assert "bas".equals(obj.getFoo("foo", false));

    Expectations.assertSatisfied();
  }

  public static class MyClass {
    public String getFoo(String str, boolean bool) {
      if (bool) {
        return "foo";
      } else {
        return "bar";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The downside is that it requires Java 5/6.

Comment: yes, can really recommend this

Comment: Just an update: the JMockit project moved to http://code.google.com/p/jmockit. It has evolved A LOT since this post (and still is evolving), and now has extensive documentation.

Comment: JMockit has moved again. It's now available at Github. http://jmockit.github.io

Answer (score 15):

You could also have a look at testing using Groovy. In Groovy you can easily mock Java interfaces using the 'as' operator:

```
def request = [isUserInRole: { roleName -> roleName == "testRole"}] as HttpServletRequest
```

Apart from this basic functionality Groovy offers a lot more on the mocking front, including the powerful `MockFor` and `StubFor` classes.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Mocks

Answer (score 12):

I started using mocks with [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/). Easy enough to understand, but the replay step was kinda annoying. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) removes this, also has a cleaner syntax as it looks like readability was one of its primary goals. I cannot stress enough how important this is, since most of developers will spend their time reading and maintaining existing code, not creating it.

Another nice thing is that interfaces and implementation classes are handled in the same way, unlike in EasyMock where still you need to remember (and check) to use an EasyMock Class Extension.

I've taken a quick look at [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/) recently, and while the laundry list of features is pretty comprehensive, I think the price of this is legibility of resulting code, and having to write more.

For me, Mockito hits the sweet spot, being easy to write and read, and dealing with majority of the situations most code will require. Using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) would be my choice.

One thing to consider is that the tool you would choose if you were developing by yourself, or in a small tight-knit team, might not be the best to get for a large company with developers of varying skill levels. Readability, ease of use and simplicity would need more consideration in the latter case. No sense in getting the ultimate mocking framework if a lot of people end up not using it or not maintaining the tests.

Comment: +1 This answer need more upvotes. One should share what they actually liked or not about the framework. Just "I used this.. and I liked it!" is one of the reasons why such good questions get closed on SO.

Answer (score 11):

We are heavily using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org) and EasyMock Class Extension at work and are pretty happy with it. It basically gives you everything you need. Take a look at the documentation, there's a very nice example which shows you all the features of EasyMock.

Comment: In my question, I was more looking for what you like and dislike about a mock framework.  I can find the documentation and read all about it - I want to know what the people who have used it think of it.

Comment: EasyMock only works on Java 5 and above, argh!

Answer (score 8):

I used JMock early. I've tried Mockito at my last project and liked it. More concise, more cleaner. PowerMock covers all needs which are absent in Mockito, such as mocking a static code, mocking an instance creation, mocking final classes and methods. So I have all I need to perform my work.

Answer (score 6):

I like JMock because you are able to set up expectations. This is totally different from checking if a method was called found in some mock libraries. Using JMock you can write very sophisticated expectations. See the jmock [cheat-sheat](http://www.jmock.org/cheat-sheet.html).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Mockito is a great framework. I use it together with [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) and [Google guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to setup my tests.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution to mocking is to have the machine do all the work with automated specification-based testing. For Java, see [ScalaCheck](http://www.scalacheck.org/) and the [Reductio](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.17/javadoc/fj/test/package-summary.html) framework included in the [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) library. With automated specification-based testing frameworks, you supply a specification of the method under test (a property about it that should be true) and the framework generates tests as well as mock objects, automatically.

For example, the following property tests the Math.sqrt method to see if the square root of any positive number n squared is equal to n.

```
val propSqrt = forAll { (n: Int) => (n >= 0) ==> scala.Math.sqrt(n*n) == n }
```

When you call `propSqrt.check()`, ScalaCheck generates hundreds of integers and checks your property for each, also automatically making sure that the edge cases are covered well.

Even though ScalaCheck is written in Scala, and requires the Scala Compiler, it's easy to test Java code with it. The Reductio framework in Functional Java is a pure Java implementation of the same concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Mockito also provides the option of stubbing methods, matching arguments (like anyInt() and anyString()), verifying the number of invocations (times(3), atLeastOnce(), never()), [and more](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

I've also found that Mockito is [simple and clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java#23048).

One thing I don't like about Mockito is that you [can't stub static methods](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: This answer is inaccurate.  You are not limited to interfaces with jMock.  You can mock concrete classes with the ClassImposteriser.

Comment: You can do exactly same things with EasyMock as well.

Comment: I've removed the inaccuracies from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For something a little different, you could use [JRuby](http://jruby.codehaus.org/) and [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) which are combined in [JtestR](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JTESTR/Home) to write tests for your Java code in expressive and succinct Ruby. There are some useful mocking examples with JtestR [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JTESTR/Mocks). One advantage of this approach is that mocking concrete classes is very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I started using mocks through JMock, but eventually transitioned to use EasyMock. EasyMock was just that, --easier-- and provided a syntax that felt more natural. I haven't switched since.