# How to go about mocking a class with final methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, legacy-code

Say I have class A with

```
class A {
  final String foo() {
    // .. computing result, contacting database, whatever ..
    return "some computed value";
  }
  // ... and a bazillion other methods, some of them final.
}
```

Now I have class B with

```
class B {
  String methodIWantToTest(A a) {
      String output = a.foo();
      // ... whatever this method does, e.g.:
      output += "_suffix";
      return output;
  }
}
```

How would I go about unit testing this method? The reason `foo()` is final is because we don't want our classes which extend A to change its functionality. But at the same time to truly unit test the method, I don't want it to reach out and run the actual `A.foo()` method.

Is there a way to, say, remove the final keyword and add an annotation along the lines of `@finalUnlessTest`? What would you recommend? Refactoring A to an interface would be very, very difficult, seeing as how it's one of our central classes and is unfortunately <s>pretty</s> extremely coupled.

**Edit #1** Sorry, forgot to mention, we're talking Java. We are not using a mocking framework as of yet.

**Answer** OK, so: wow. [JMockit](http://jmockit.org) is just incredible and is in my eyes the killer app for testing legacy code. Unbelievably useful especially in my case. Thanks so much! You basically would do something like the following for my psuedo-example:

```
class AMock {
   final String foo() {
     return "myTestValue";
   }
}
class Test extends TestCase {
   A mockedA;
   B b;
   protected void setUp() {
      Mockit.redefineMethods( A.class, AMock.class );  // this "pipes" all mocked methods from A to AMock
      mockedA = new A();    // NOT new AMock()!!!
      b = new B();
   }
   public void testB() {
      assertEquals("myTestValue",mockedA.foo());
      assertEquals("myTestValue_suffix",b.methodIWantToTest(mockedA));
   }
}
```

Is this frickin' cool or what?

Comment: Judging from the capitalisation, this must be Java.

Comment: can you tell us what language you use (looks like java)? some answers can be language dependant, also tell us what mocking framework you use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the [JMockit](http://jmockit.org) mocking library.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the "final" and just put in a comment "Don't override this method!!". If you can't trust coworkers not to follow simple instructions, it's hopeless anyway.

Comment: ...except we're not just talking about coworkers, since customers can use our API...

Answer (score 0):

The following code will also allow you to do it. I am not saying that this is good practice, but it is an interesting use (abuse?) of anonymous classes.

```
public class Jobber {

    public final String foo() {
        return fooFactory() ;
    }

    String fooFactory() {
        return "jobber" ;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Jobber jobber = new Jobber() { String fooFactory() { return "prefix " + super.fooFactory() ;} } ;

        System.out.println(jobber.foo() );
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmn. seems harsh to mark this down without giving a reason. I guess I shouldn't take these things personally. 

There is an interesting article which discusses this strategy of testing objects here... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest.html