# Is it possible to do strict mocks with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I'd like to use strict mocks, at least when developing for the first time some tests against old code, so any methods invoked on my mock will throw an exception if I didn't specifically define expectations.

From what I've come to see, Mockito if I didn't define any expectations will just return null, which will later on cause a NullPointerException in some other place.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What do you want it to do?

You can set it to [RETURN_SMART_NULLS](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS), which avoids the NPE and includes some useful info.

You could replace this with a custom implementation, for example, that throws an exception from its `answer` method:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Object mock = Mockito.mock(Object.class, new NullPointerExceptionAnswer());
    String s = mock.toString(); // Breaks here, as intended.
    assertEquals("", s);
}

class NullPointerExceptionAnswer<T> implements Answer<T> {
    @Override
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks good. Possibly the default return strategy in Mockito 2.0 as well...

Comment: Unless it can be made to throw an exception instead of returning a value, doesn't seem to be of any help..

Comment: @devouredelysium *Any* help? That's obviously wrong, even if it doesn't do what exactly what you want. Like I said, should be pretty easy to mod.

Comment: But it tells you where the null-returning method is called instead of where the null object is used. Isn't that what you're after? In some cases returning null may not cause any issues for your test so you don't need to provide a return value for it. Throwing an exception would force you to solve problems that don't affect your test...

Comment: @devouredelysium Like by throwing an exception from its `answer` method.

Comment: @Dave: throwing an exception from an answer method assumes I know beforehand what methods are going to be called. As stated in the OP, that's precisely what I am looking for!

Comment: @devouredelysium Ah, okay--cool :) I guess I can see the need for both, although I'd probably throw a more-specific exception so it's clear what happened. Glad this capability was added, though.

Comment: @avh You could use `doReturn("X").when(mock).toString()`

Answer (score 12):

You could use `verifyNoMoreInteractions`. It's useful if the tested class catches exceptions.

```
@Test
public void testVerifyNoMoreInteractions() throws Exception {
    final MyInterface mock = Mockito.mock(MyInterface.class);

    new MyObject().doSomething(mock);

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock); // throws exception
}

private static class MyObject {
    public void doSomething(final MyInterface myInterface) {
        try {
            myInterface.doSomethingElse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}

private static interface MyInterface {
    void doSomethingElse();
}
```

Result:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NoInteractionsWanted: 
No interactions wanted here:
-> at hu.palacsint.CatchTest.testVerifyNoMoreInteractions(CatchTest.java:18)
But found this interaction:
-> at hu.palacsint.CatchTest$MyObject.doSomething(CatchTest.java:24)
Actually, above is the only interaction with this mock.
    at hu.palacsint.stackoverflow.y2013.q8003278.CatchTest.testVerifyNoMoreInteractions(CatchTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Add this `@Rule` to your test class as a public field:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class MyClassTests {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS);

    @Test
    ....
}
```

This value was added to Mockito in version [2.3.0](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/quality/Strictness.html#STRICT_STUBS)

From the documentation:

> Ensures clean tests, reduces test code duplication, improves
>   debuggability. Offers best combination of flexibility and
>   productivity. Highly recommended. Planned as default for Mockito v3.
>   Adds following behavior:
>
> - Improved productivity: the test fails early when code under test
>     invokes stubbed method with different arguments (see
>     PotentialStubbingProblem).
> - Cleaner tests without unnecessary
>     stubbings: the test fails when unused stubs are present (see
>     UnnecessaryStubbingException).
> - Cleaner, more DRY tests ("Don't Repeat
>     Yourself"): If you use Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(Object...) you
>     no longer need to explicitly verify stubbed invocations. They are
>     automatically verified for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS it selects its "what to do if no expectation" from a global setting. 
Furthermore "If there is no global configuration then it uses {@link ReturnsEmptyValues} (returns zeros, empty collections, nulls, etc.)"
I have not yet been able to make that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `MockitoRule` approach, if you don't need to use a specific test runner (and you are using Mockito 2.5.1 or higher), you could also consider using the `MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs` runner, i.e.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
```

(I would have commented on the post about MockitoRule, but don't have that ability yet)

Answer (score -1):

Bellow Methods can verify no unexpected method called:

```
org.mockito.Mockito#only
org.mockito.Mockito#verifyNoMoreInteractions
```