# How to mock entire JAX-RPC communication session?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jax-rpc

I have a legacy application, which is working with third-party web service through JAX-RPC. Now I need to unit-test the application by mocking certain XML RPC calls with test data. Actually, I need to replace [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/), which is used by the application, by some other library that will be JAX-RPC compliant, but will return what I'm telling it to return. I'm pretty sure I'm not alone with such a problem... Are there any open source libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Spring framework and EasyMock.

[What's the best mock framework for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697/752366)

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/).  It's a Jetty server that you set up programmatically to respond to certain request patterns with content that you also specify.  I have been able to set it up to respond to XML-RPC requests from my class.  E.g.,

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/RPC2"))
        .withRequestBody(containing("<methodName>...</methodName>"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withBody("<methodResponse>...</methodResponse>")));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mocking the calls to external services you can use `EasyMock+Powermock` or `Mockito`
you can do something like this

```
Easymock.expect(your function calling external Systems).andReturn(your required output)
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!