# Testing the transmission of DatagramSockets

Tags: java, unit-testing, sockets, datagram

I want to test my program which sends `DatagramSocket` data between a *sender* and a *receiver* class. How should I go about testing that data is being sent between the classes?

Here is my Sender code...

```
public class CheckIn {

    private String patientName;
    private String pTime;
    private int portnumber;

    public CheckIn(String pname, String time, int port){
        patientName = pname;
        pTime = time;
        portnumber = port;
        process();
    }

    public void process() {
        try {
            DatagramSocket is = new DatagramSocket(5800,InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            String n = "Your "+"\n" + pTime + "\n" + patientName + " has arrived";
            oos.writeObject(n);
            byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            oos.close();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portnumber);
            is.send(packet);

            System.out.println( "patient name " + patientName );
            System.out.println( "Check In");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR Cashier: " + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Receiver class...

```
class Reciever2 extends Thread {
    public Reciever2(){
        this.start();   //starts the thread
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5700,InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            System.out.println( "Recieving" );   //prints when receiving a message

            while (true){
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];    //array of bytes
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length);  
                socket.receive(packet);      //receives the packet
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData()); 
                ObjectInputStream ois =  new ObjectInputStream(bais);
                String s = (String) ois.readObject();   //reading the data
                bais.close();   //closes input stream
                ois.close();   //closes input stream

                System.out.println(s);
                theText.setText( s);   //displays message
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR Cook: " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest be just to write a receiver?

Comment: @Erik - yes, that's what I would do, adding the code into the CheckIn class.  Then replace the magic '5800' port number with a ctor parameter and a add a port to receive from.  Then make two of them with complementary ports, then pass them to a couple pairs of  threads, then fire in one datagram and watch as it circulates round.

Comment: Hmm. only need two threads - each waits for datagrams and, on receipt,  sends them out again.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to write a receiver class for testing against, or have access to the destination server so you can observe the change. The UDP protocol is pretty much a one-way protocol.

This guide might be useful to understand more about `DatagramSockets` - it also has a section on writing a sender and receiver.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html

Comment: Well, isn't the reciver class working? If it is, just print out the values in the packages as you recive them

Comment: Well, start the Receiver program, then start your Sender program - you should be able to see whether they are talking to each other, especially if you're using an IDE like Eclipse and can set a debugger breakpoint in the Receiver.

Comment: yes the reciever class works.. just wanted like a jUnit orJmock test to show it works but the reciever class recieves it an displays on a GUI

Answer (score 0):

You could use a technique called Mocking. 
See [What's the best mock framework for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java) for more information.