# Patching Java classes with a mock implementation in a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class A which instantiates an object from class B internally.  That second class has lots of external side-effects, e.g. it uses a network connection.

```
public class A {
  private B b;
  public A() {
    b = new B(); // 3rd party class that calls out externally (e.g. to a db)
  }
}
```

I would like to unit test class A by providing a mock implementation of class B.  I can easily create a mocked version of B by writing my own class or using something like Mockito and other frameworks, but how do I inject this mock implementation into class A's code?

I guess I could ask for an instance of class B in class A's constructor, but that seems ugly.  No one really needs to know how class A does it's  business.

Python has a "mock" library that allows you to "patch" functions at run time during a test.  Does Java have something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best mock framework for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java)

Comment: In my experience, the easiest way to create a "mock object" is to just:  1) Create a new .java file with the same class/filename, 2) copy/paste all the public methods, 3) add the bare minimum needed to "do something", and 4) modify my project so the build will pick up the new, "mock" class instead of the "real" class.  IMHO...

Comment: A common solution to this is "dependency injection". Basically this means you avoid doing "b = new B();" in your constructors precisely to preserve "testability". Instead you *always* have the objects you need provided from the outside. This means there's no difference between using a real or a mock object as far as `A` is concerned.

Comment: Good links: [The Concept of Mocking](http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/the-concept-of-mocking.html), and [Testing with EasyMock](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EasyMock/article.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario I typically have a 2nd package (default) scope constuctor that allows you to pass a mock in for testing purposes.

```
public class A {
  private B b;

  /*
  *  Used by clients
  */
  public A() {
    this(new B());
  }

  /*
  * Used by unit test
  * 
  * @param b A mock implementation of B
  */
  A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that this is probably the best compromise without employing something like Spring. I'm going to see if I can use DI to fix this more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mockito.](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)  Ultimately, based on your design, you'll need to use reflection to get the mock instance of B into A.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to solve with the JMockit mocking API:

```
public class ATest
{
    @Test
    public void myTest(@Mocked B mockB)
    {
        // Record expectations on "mockB", if needed.

        new A().doSomethingUsingB();

        // Verify expectations on "mockB", if applicable.
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this mock class B's constructor?  If not, then this is not what the original question is asking for.

Comment: Yes, it will. All constructors and methods (including `static`, `final`, `private`, etc.) in the `@Mocked` class *are* mocked.