# How to run JUnit test case with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, junit

I am trying to run Junit test case for my application where one of my method call the server to get the location from geo-coordinates, however it is not connecting to the server URL as my tomcat server is not started and even if I start my tomcat server I am enable to find the location. Can anyone guide me through this or do I need to do the configuration between Junit and Tomcat.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use some mock libraries to mock the object rather than getting it from server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java