# Mocking Db in Java Unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unit test this code block in a method in my service layer. 
Could anyone suggest what can (/should) I test here and how to test them (esp. the insert to db part). Any pointers (/example code/doc) will be very helpful.

```
if (element != null) {
    id = iplDAO.loadGames(element, batchVO.getId());
    iplPartyDetailsVO = element.getParty();
    if iplPartyDetailsVO != null) {
    try {
        iplDAO.insertPartyDetails(iplPartyDetailsVO, id, batchVO.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.logp("className");
        String err = "blah";
        iplDAO.insertIntoError(err_t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you own the DAO code or is it proprietary?

Comment: Can you share how the `iplDAO` is created/initialized?

Comment: @Compass
Yes we own DAO code - its created as below:
'public class IPLDAO extends BaseDAO implements TTDAO {
 At-Autowired
 private ITXXDAO txxDao;
 At-Override
 public int loadGames(..) {
 return id;
        }
 At-Override
 public boolean insertPartyDetails(a, b, c) {
  return x;
 }
}'
And in the service class its Autowired

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing the testing with the mocking, if you are trying to write tests for this service layer code then you need to decide what are your expectations, for example:

- Load some games from a data source
- Save something (it's not clear in your code what you are actually saving but writing some unit tests might make this more obvious).

So if these *are* your expectations for your code then you would need to write a test that can verify that they have been met.

This means [mocking the dependency](https://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/) that you are calling (in your case the iplDAO object) so that each method call returns something that can be used to test your functionality - in your case these two calls:

```
 iplDAO.loadGames(element,batchVO.getId())
```

and

```
iplDAO.insertPartyDetails(iplPartyDetailsVO, id,batchVO.getId());
```

There are lots of [Java mocking libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java?rq=1) to choose from and they are all well documented but [this blog post](https://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks - so you recommend testing those to dao calls?
now my questions is how do I test iplDAO.insertPartyDetails(iplPartyDetailsVO, id,batchVO.getId()); without an actual insert? (Can a db mock help? if so can you please point me to an example)

Comment: @user2666282 By using a mock iplDAO object in your class (for example by using Mockito library) you are replacing what the 'real' iplDAO object normally does (presumably the read and insert to the DB).  So there will be no interaction with the database.

If you post the whole class then it will be easier to give an example.